# Cloned a HTML TR with Jquery. Need each clone to submit seperate SQL INSERT

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

As the title states. I have cloned a HTML TR with the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
          $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #stock').val('');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #hand').val('');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #returned').val('');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #received').val('');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #stockhand').val('');
             $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #request').val('');
             $("#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {this.reset();});

             return false;
        });
    });
```

The problem I face is that when I use the information in the cloned TR (Which is basic text inputs) and click the submit button, it only send the SQL data for the last TR. I need it to send a separate SQL INSERT command for each TR for that form. I am not clued up on JQuery and figure i probably need to create a new ID or something for each clone and send the SQL if the id = example. However I am as of yet unable to get this right.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated?

(The SQL is obviously being called in PHP as this is a PHP website that is running script inside with HTML elements as well)

EDIT:

DOM Source of Selection:

```
<a class="button" id="add1">+</a>
              <label>Old Devices/Removed from Site</label>
  <form action="?action" method="post">
                <table id="oldDevTable" style="width:100px; align:center" class="center">
             <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
             <select name="Devices_Removed_From_Site">
          <option value="example">Example</option>
</select>
                </td>
                <td>
<input id="hand" name="prevWeek" placeholder="On hand prev week" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input id="stock" name="usedStock" placeholder="Stock used" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input id="returned" name="returnedStock" placeholder="Stock returned" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input id="received" name="receivedStock" placeholder="Stock received" type="text">
</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: So all the generated inputs have the same ID, right? Yes, this should change. But based on your description, I'd expect that the data in the first tr would be submitted rather than the last. So maybe there is something else going on. Can you provide a sample of what the generated HTML looks like? (E.G. in Firefox, select the table and do "View Selection Source".)

Comment: I have edited and added what I think you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple inputs with same name,then last element value will be taken in server side(eg: php),duplicate id's also need to be fixed as it will cause undefined behaviour upon accessing via javascript.
You need to set name and id of newly inserted tr elements dynamicaly like
 $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #hand').attr('name','hand[1]');
 $('#oldDevTable tbody>tr:last #hand').attr('id','hand-1');
You may consider get the tr count and increment it by 1 and append to id,name.

Comment: This is great. so this changes the id to hand-1 or each new tr that is created. Now I need to get it to increase by 1 as you state. Will do some research into that thanks.